# How to convert a polygon to a grid of polygons using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector-grid

For example, the city of Rotterdam represented as a hexagonal grid.

[image: Rotterdam hexagon urban identity]

Comment: Do you have any restrictions regarding custom size of these hexes, or anything else? Because one way would be to do a voronoi diagram - the opposite of Delauney triangulation on a set of points which wouldnt be so hard to generate.

Answer (score 4):

The [MMQGIS](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/) plugin has a **Create Grid Layer Tool**. You can use that to create a vector grid layer and then intersect it with your city boundaries polygon.

Comment: Could you please explain how to intersect the vector grid with the city boundaries polygon?

Comment: What attributes does your city boundaries have btw? It would be great if you could upload the file so we can test the workflow on your file. What is it for btw? Just visualization?

Comment: It's just a visualazation. For example, here are some [shapefiles for NYC](http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/html/bytes/dwndistricts.shtml).

Comment: To intersect the vector grid and your city polygon: Vector> GeoProcessing Tools> Intersect...